# C++17 filesystem using nuwen MinGW on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, c++17, mingw-w64, gcc8

I wanted to try out the new filesystem library in C++17, so tried copying the [std::filesystem::current_path example from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) and compiling it using the latest version (16.0) of the [MinGW distribution from nuwen.net](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) on my Windows 10 x64 machine.  This includes gcc v8.1 which should support the filesystem library according to [cppreference.com compiler support page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Here is the code that I am trying to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Current path is " << fs::current_path() << '\n';
}
```

And the compiler command I am using:

```
g++ -std=c++17 filesystem_test.cpp
```

Here is the error I am getting when trying to compile:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h: In member function 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path& std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::operator/=(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&)':
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:47: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iosfwd:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\postypes.h:221:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _StateT> bool std::operator!=(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)'
     operator!=(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\postypes.h:221:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::fpos<_StateT>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_pair.h:456:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)'
     operator!=(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_pair.h:456:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:311:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Iterator> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)'
     operator!=(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:311:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:349:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)'
     operator!=(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:349:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:1124:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)'
     operator!=(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:1124:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:1130:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Iterator> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&)'
     operator!=(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:1130:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\allocator.h:158:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator!=(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)'
     operator!=(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\allocator.h:158:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::allocator<_CharT>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\allocator.h:164:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp> bool std::operator!=(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_CharT>&)'
     operator!=(const allocator<_Tp>&, const allocator<_Tp>&)
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\allocator.h:164:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::allocator<_CharT>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\basic_string.h:48,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string:52,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string_view:454:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> constexpr bool std::operator!=(std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>, std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>)'
     operator!=(basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string_view:454:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\basic_string.h:48,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string:52,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string_view:460:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> constexpr bool std::operator!=(std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>, std::__detail::__idt<std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> >)'
     operator!=(basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string_view:460:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\basic_string.h:48,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string:52,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string_view:466:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> constexpr bool std::operator!=(std::__detail::__idt<std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> >, std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>)'
     operator!=(__detail::__idt<basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>> __x,
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string_view:466:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string:52,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\basic_string.h:6056:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)'
     operator!=(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\basic_string.h:6056:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' is not derived from 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string:52,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\basic_string.h:6069:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const _CharT*, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)'
     operator!=(const _CharT* __lhs,
     ^~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\basic_string.h:6069:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\filesystem:37,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\fs_path.h:237:60: note:   mismatched types 'const _CharT*' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path'
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                                                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\string:52,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\iostream:39,
                 from filesystem_test.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\c++\8.1.0\bits\basic_string.h:6081:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)'
     operator!=(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^~~~~~~~
<snip>
```

Note I had to snip the end of the error message to reduce the character count for this question.  I have put the entire error message here: https://pastebin.com/pnfMnMs7

Edit: As per Galik's comment, I tried changing my compiler command to

```
g++ -std=c++17 filesystem_test.cpp -lstdc++fs
```

However I seem to get exactly the same error as before

Comment: @Galik, as you thought, this did not change the error I was getting, but thanks for pointing that out, I am assuming that would have been the next stumbling block after this one!

Comment: Does the *filesystem TS* work? If you change to `#include <experimental/filesystem>` and `namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;`?

Comment: @Galik, I get a no such file or directory error when trying to `#include <experimental/filesystem>`

Comment: Does anything else work? Have you tried compiling something without *filesystem*?

Comment: A standard Hello World test compiles properly

Comment: [Seems to be a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/737/).

Comment: Just fired up an arch linux vagrant box and the same code compiled just fine on there, definitely seems to be related to the bug that @zett42 linked to

Answer (score 4):

try latest [msys2](http://www.msys2.org/) instead of nuwen distro:

1. pacman -Syu
2. pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
3. gcc -v

   $ gcc -v
   Using built-in specs.
   COLLECT_GCC=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
   Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
   Configured with: ../gcc-8.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
   Thread model: posix
   gcc version 8.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)

Comment: Current g++ version distributed with msys2 is 9.1.0. That is just great.